# Sass Variable Argument and Variable with default value in the same Mixin

Tags: sass, mixins

In Sass is it possible to put a variable argument and a variable with a default value all wrapped inside one mixin?
Here is what I've been trying

```
@mixin p($size: 20px, $font-fam...){
  font-family: $font-fam;
  font-size: $size;
}
```

I know that a default value normally should be put on the end but in this case $font-fam would think it was a part of its own variable.
Is this possible or will I just need to separate out the mixin for it to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think variable arguments can have a default value, but you can check if the variable exists, and if not then set its value:

```
@mixin p($size: 20px, $font-fam...){
    @if length($font-fam) == 0 {
        $font-fam: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    }
    font-family: $font-fam;
    font-size: $size;
}
```